# Load Material UI AutoComplete suggestions after user input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, autocomplete, material-ui

I have an Autocomplete component that is required to load a massive data list (up to 6000 elements) and show suggestions accordingly to the user's input.

As the data options have so many elements, whenever the user starts typing in a slow computer, it slows down and requires some time to load everything. I have to prevent it, so I came with an idea to show the user suggestions after they typed the third character. It's even giving me this error whenever the user clicks on the input box:

> Warning: React instrumentation encountered an error: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded console.

I need to show the suggestions after the third character input. I have tried to use the [getOptionDisabled suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63235562/how-to-limit-material-ui-autocomplete-multiple-selections-to-one-group) and the limitTags, but they did not work.

Here is the code:

```react
const NameSelect = (props) => {
  return (
    <Dialog>
        <React.Fragment>
          <DialogTitle id="search-name-dialog-title">
            Search name
          </DialogTitle>
          <DialogContent>
                <Autocomplete
                  id="combo-box-client-select"
                  options={props.NameList}
                  value={props.preSelectedName}
                  
                  getOptionLabel={(option) =>
                    option.Name_name +
                    ", " +
                    option.country +
                    ", " +
                    option.city
                  }
                  onChange={(object, value) => {
                    props.preSelectedNameSet(value);
                  }}
                  renderInput={(params) => (
                    <TextField
                      {...params}
                      label="Search name"
                      variant="outlined"
                      fullWidth
                    />
                  )}
                />
              .
              .
              .
    </Dialog>
  );
};
```

Can someone please help me with that approach, or suggest a better one? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe solved in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43972317/how-to-achieve-minimum-character-length-feature-in-react-material-uis-autocompl)?

Comment: @JosepJoestar The popoverProps does not exist in the recent Material UI versions. If I use the prop ''Open'', it works when I open the autocomplete component, but it does not get updated whenever the user types in.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<Autocomplete
    inputValue={inputValue}
    onInputChange={(e) => setinputValue(event.target.value)}
    id="combo-box-demo"
    options={values}
    getOptionLabel={(option) => option}
    style={{ width: 300 }}
    renderInput={(params) => (
      <TextField {...params} label="Combo box" variant="outlined" />
    )}
    open={inputValue.length > 2}
  />
```

Use `InputValue` prop to trigger the auto complete drop down.
Example : [auto complete dropdown](https://3eyfb.csb.app/)

Comment: I have used your solution and changed a few things for the autocomplete to not appear without focus. Thanks!

Comment: For closing dropdown when focus is lost, useState for open and use onBlur method in autocomplete to set the state to false

Answer (score 1):

My idea is to add a state for Autocomplete current value to watch for its `autoComplete` property. That state will look something like this:

```
  const [currentValue, useCurrentValue] = useState(props.preSelectedName);
```

so that your component will look something like this:

```
<Autocomplete
autoComplete={currentValue.length >= 3 ? true : false}
onChange={useCurrentValue}
   ...your other properties     
                />
```

Another idea: you might wanna use `setTimeout` in your `onChange` method to slow down the re-render. But don't forget to `clearTimeout` before you set them.

Answer (score 0):

The feature that you require is known as "Debouncing" and it is used whenever time consuming tasks occur frequently. In your case it, everytime you type the key, the suggestions are computed and this will definetely lead to lagging.

Lodash's `debounce` function will implement this for you.

As far as my knowledge, I am not sure whether you can implement this with MUI Autocomplete, but a custom solution you can do something like this:-

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react"; 
import { _ } from "lodash";


function AutoComplete() {  
 const [input, setInput] = useState("");   
 const [suggestions, setSuggestions] = useState([]);

  const updateInput = (input) => {
    setInput(input);
    /*_.debounce will fire the setSuggestions
     and fetchSuggestions only after a gap of 3000ms */
    _.debounce((input) => setSuggestions(fetchSuggestions(input), 3000));   
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        value={input}
        class="input"
        onChange={(event) => updateInput(event.target.value)}
      />
      <div class="suggestions">
        <ul>
          {suggestions?.length > 0 &&
            suggestions?.map((val, idx) => (
              <li class="suggestion" key={idx}>
                {val}
              </li>
            ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>   
  ); 
}
  


export default AutoComplete;
```

You can style the components using the appropriate styles and materialize.css so that you get a functional replica of the Autocomplete component of MUI.